# how to customise input field width in bootstrap 3

Tags: text, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

After having removed critical features such as `input-xlarge` and `input-large`, what is the substitution for it in bootstrap 3?

Of course I could use `col-lg-12` etc but that is giving an error in tab pane.

I could also use `style = "width:30px;`" but then It would loose its responsiveness unlike `input-xlarge`.Any suggestions etc?

Comment: you can fo it by using he class input-sm

Comment: The correct way is indeed to use col-md-X (see my answer below). Please clarify what your problem is with your "tab pane" (I don't know what you mean by that).

Answer (score 67):

In Bootstrap 3, `.form-control` (the class you give your inputs) has a width of 100%, which allows you to wrap them into col-lg-X divs for arrangement. Example from the docs:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-lg-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

See under [Column sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-control-sizes).

It's a bit different than in Bootstrap 2.3.2, but you get used to it quickly.

Comment: Note that you can use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding `.form-horizontal` to the form. Doing so changes `.form-groups` to behave as grid rows, so no need for `.row` - [more information](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Answer (score 6):

You can use these classes

> input-lg
>
> input

and

> input-sm

for input fields and replace **input** with **btn** for buttons.

Check this documentation http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

This will change only height of the element, to reduce the width you have to use grid system classes like `col-xs-* col-md-* col-lg-*`.

Example `col-md-3`. See doc here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: These classes don't change the width of input elements.

Comment: @eddiegroves This will change only height of the element, to reduce the width you have to use grid system classes like ``.col-xs-* .col-md-* .col-lg-*``. Example ``col-md-3``. See doc here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2):

```
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">col-xs-2</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="ex2">col-xs-3</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for="ex3">col-xs-4</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved with a `max-width` in my main css-file.

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

It's a simple solution with little "code"

Comment: The suggested style messes up grouped input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group col-md-5">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> 
            </div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" width="50px">

                    </div>
                    <input type="button" name="SIGNUP" value="SIGNUP">
            </div>
```